# How to remove a list, inside a list, inside a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, oop, dictionary, nested-lists

I'm trying to delete a list after obtaining a value from it. The list is located in a list inside a dictionary.

So far I have been tinkering with the following:

```py
for data in this.customer_data:
   for loans in data['loaned_books']:
      if val_to_pop in loans:
         print(loans[2])
         loans.pop(2)
         print(loans)
```

which gives

```
UML for dummies
[24, 'Feiten', True]
```

This comes really close to what I what I want but it becomes really fuzzy the moment I try to delete the list which the value was located. I can't seem to `remove()` and nor do I want to give it a fixed index number as it is a dynamic list

relevant code:

```py
class Customer(Person):
    def __init__(this, number, gender, given_name, surname, street_address, zip_code, city, email, username, telephone):
        super().__init__(gender, given_name, surname, street_address, zip_code, city, telephone)
        this.number = number
        this.email = email
        this.username = username
        this.customer_data = [{'number': this.number, 'gender': this.gender, 'given_name': this.given_name, 'surname': this.surname, 'street_address': this.street_address,
                               'zip_code': this.zip_code, 'city': this.city, 'email': this.email, 'username': this.username, 'telephone': this.telephone, 'loaned_books': []}]
```

stack which the key 'loaned_book' consists of:

```
[[24, 'Feiten', 'UML for dummies', True], [24, 'Feiten', 'Word Art', True]]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a gander at your here python code and I mean to think that this is what you young bloke is looking for.

```
for list in nested_list["loans"]:
    for item in list:
        if item == "myVar":
            nested["dict_key"].pop()
```

*I hope I have been of your service today and you can send me a message whenever you require assistance.*